# Why won't child Tasks finish before .ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, task, parent-child

To my understanding the ContinueWith method waits for the task in question to finish. I the case of the following code this means it's finished when it's done with it's child tasks. If this is true why does it sometimes output
0 0 0 and other times 0 1 2?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var results = new Int32[3];
                new Task(() => results[0] = 0, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                new Task(() => results[1] = 1, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                new Task(() => results[2] = 2, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                return results;
            });

        var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(n =>
        {
            foreach (Int32 i in n.Result)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        });

        finalTask.Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: @HansPassant: On the surface it looks like the child tasks are attached to the parent so the parent won't complete until the children have. Thus the OP has written code that is intended to use `ContinueWith` correctly. The problem is it didn't throw the expected Exception when the child tasks failed to attach to the parent. Minor code changes are perfectly able to get the desired result without touching the `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

> When you pass an Action to Task.Run:
>
> `Task.Run(someAction);`
>
> that’s exactly equivalent to:
>
> `Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction,` 
>       `CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);`

This looks to me like it will be stopping the children from attaching as expected.

Indeed changing the start line to

```
Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
```

does seem to fix the issue. I've come to this conclusion by looking at what they did differently on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx which uses the `Factory.StartNew` method instead of `Run`.

Having said that I'm not sure why it isn't throwing an `InvalidOperationException` when you try to attach the tasks...